# Intersection with ${x > 30}$ and ${x > 10}$

Tags: probability

I am doing a question of conditional probability.

Why does:
$$P[x > 30 | x > 10] = \frac{p[x>30] \cap p[x>10]}{p[x>10]} = \frac{p[x>30]}{p[x>10]}$$

and not:
$$P[x > 30 | x > 10] = \frac{p[x>30] \cap p[x>10]}{p[x>10]} = \frac{p[x>10]}{p[x>10]}$$

Comment: Do you know Bayes' Theorem? Also, note that $P[x>10\mid x>30]=1$.

Comment: Do you mean by $[x > 30 | x > 10]$ the intersection $$(x > 30) \cap (x > 10)$$ or $[x > 30]$ given that $[x>10]$??

Comment: So we have
$$
P[x>30\mid x>10]=\frac{P[(x>30)\cap (x>10)]}{P[x>10]}
$$and you're wondering why the numerator simplifies to $P[x>30]$?

Comment: Yeah I meant the intersection, my bad on wording the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple.$ P\big((x>30) \cap (x>10)\big) =P(x>30)$ because the former is a subset of later. Former is $(30,\infty) $while later is $(10,\infty)$